Can I use Zoom Workplace in a way such that I am not charged?
This evening, I scheduled a meeting with my sisters for this weekend. I decided to use Zoom, which I find good for short meetings. However, I am not a frequent user of Zoom. It's been over a year since I last used it.
I got into Zoom; it immediately wanted me to upgrade to something called Zoom Workplace. I figured this was just some random update, so I went ahead and upgraded. I proceeded with schedule the meeting with my sisters, then I was about to leave, when it started talking about fees, etc., for its AI that's a part of Zoom Workplace.
Heck, I don't want an AI for Zoom. I just want to have my meeting with my sisters, then leave Zoom alone for another year or more. So, here's the questions:

Is it possible to use Zoom Workplace without the AI features or anything else that will invoke a charge?
If the answer to that is yes, then what do we leave out?
If the answer to no, then how do I downgrade back to the basic, free version of Zoom?


Zoom Workplace is a paid service. Just cancel your subscription. Go to the Zoom website to cancel your subscription. If you still cannot figure it out contact their customer support. As your problem has to do with cancellation of a paid service this question really isn’t within scope.. Since their website is subject to change, often, I am hesitant to even vote to migrate this question.

Thank you, @Ramhound

Yes, Zoom still has a free option, with limitations: only two parties, max of 40 minutes per meeting (though you can still log in again after 40 minutes... until they remove that option). BTW Zoom has simply changed name to Zoom Workplace for both free and paid options.

@DrMoishePippikn- I assumed by the name Workplace was an upgrade or name for the paid service. Does not matter you can still cancel.
